# Temporal Analysis Tool: Seeking

Tags: analysis, tools, spatio-temporal-data

I am looking for an alternative tool (proprietary or FOSS) that matches the  [functionality](http://releasenotes.dhigroup.com/2008/TArelinf.htm) of Temporal Analyst for ArcGIS by  [DHI Software](http://www.mikebydhi.com). The best I could get was the QGIS plugin  [Time Manager](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/time-manager-0-3-released/)  whose functionality I perceive is more for visualisation than analytical (similar to esri's Time Slider.)

[*Data Analysis - the Temporal Analyst for ArcGIS offers a suite of tools for data analysis and processing, incl. basic statistics and arithmetics, time step resampling, gapfiling, distribution and CDF plots, duration curves, double mass and double scatter.*]

I am not a statistician nor hardcore developer so the more the "point and click" I can get the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe **[Multitemporal Multivariate data visualization plugin](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Multitemporal-Multivariate-data-visualization-plugin-td4104549.html) for QGIS** is closer to what you're looking for.

Screenshot: http://www.bernawebdesign.ch/byteblog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/multiview.png

Comment: and if the included visualisations do not suffice you the plugin can easily be expanded to include new visualizations if needed.

Comment: That's what I am looking for, thanks. [looks like an eventual  migration to QGIS is unevitable. :-) ]

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting implementation from a former professor of mine at the University of Tennessee from a National Science Foundation project titled "Towards a GIS-based Analytical Time-geographic Framework for Physical and Virtual Activities:

http://web.utk.edu/~sshaw/NSF-Project-Website/default.htm

From the project web page: "The major goal of this project is to extend Hägerstrand’s time geography such that it can provide a comprehensive framework of representing and modeling both physical and virtual activities as well as the interactions between them. In addition, this research will design a space-time geographic information system (GIS) to implement the extended time-geographic framework."

--Tom

Comment: Been playing with the extension, 'quick' results - am familiar with esri environment. The QGIS plugin seems the comprehensive solution.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[ESRI Tracking Analyst](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/trackinganalyst/index.html)